# Do you know addon can export gltf aniamtion by selected NLA strips?

Tags: rigging, blenderkit

My working company is building a Aframe web game.
I built an animated character and placed in NLA editor in blender and export gltf to aframe by NLA actions.
However, I would like to select servals NLA strips to export.
What addon do you recommend like auto rig pro : action manager.